# is it impossible to modify size of column having char type in Derby?

Tags: database, derby

I wanna modify size of column having CHAR type in Derby.
- existing size of the column = CHAR(2)
- the size i want = CHAR(3)

ALTER TABLE Test
    ALTER LOG SET DATA TYPE CHAR(4)

But, if i try that, "only VARCHAR, CLOB, or BLOB Type is possible" is printed...

SO, is it impossible to modify size of column having char type in Derby?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a simple 1-line `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` statement to change a `CHAR` data type; see https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html

You can, however, use a more complicated 4-step process:

1. `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ...` to add a new `CHAR(3)` column
2. `UPDATE ... SET ...` to set the new column's values from the old column's values.
3. `ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN ...` to drop the `CHAR(2)` column
4. `RENAME COLUMN` to rename the `CHAR(3)` column to have the same name as the old `CHAR(2)` column.

Naturally, make a backup of your database first before running commands like these.